# What properties does this function have?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  be an $\textbf{uniformly continuous}$ function. Then by definition $\forall\epsilon>0 \quad \exists\delta>0\quad$such that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},\quad\mid{}x-y \mid{}<\delta\implies \mid{} f(x) -f(y) \mid{}<\epsilon$.

Define $\Delta_{\epsilon}=\{\delta>0\ \colon\;\mid{}x-y \mid{}<\delta\implies \mid{} f(x) -f(y) \mid{}<\epsilon\}$ for a fixed positive $\epsilon$.

Since $f$ is an uniformly continuous function $\Delta_{\epsilon}\ne\emptyset$. If $\Delta_{\epsilon}$ is bounded above, then by the $\textbf{least upper bound property}$ of the real numbers $\sup{\Delta_{\epsilon}}$ exists.

Now we define the following function:

\begin{align*}
g \colon  \mathbb{R^{+}} &\rightarrow \mathbb{R^{+}} \\
\epsilon &\mapsto \sup{\Delta_{\epsilon}}&\text{when} \ \Delta_{\epsilon}\ \text{is bounded above}  \\
\epsilon &\mapsto 0 \ &\text{when}\ \Delta_{\epsilon}\ \text{isn't bounded above}
\end{align*}

What can we say about function $g$? When is it continuous? When is it differentiable?

If the question is too broad, try giving an answer for the functions $sin(x)$ and $\sqrt{x}.$ I've tried but I haven't found an easy way to find the supremum.

Comment: will $\inf \Delta_{\epsilon}$ not be 0 every time? if $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - y|< \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - y| < \frac{\delta}{2} $

Comment: Indeed. I didn't want to ask that. I've edited the question. Take another look at it.

Comment: For a specific $f$ it appears $g$ is a constant. Do you want to simultaneously look at the $g$ associated to all uniformly continuous $f$? [It looks like that would be infinite.] Or some family of uniformly continuous $f$?

Comment: No. Fix a uniform continuous function $f$ and for all epsilon try to find the supremum of all deltas that makes the function uniformly continuous. We know some delta exists by hypothesis. I don't think g is constant since if we make epsilon smaller and smaller fewer deltas will do the job.

Comment: @coffeemath The point is that the epsilon in $\Delta_{\epsilon}$ is fixed. There was a mistake in the writing.